# Flot fill color above a line graph

Tags: jquery, charts, flot

http://jsfiddle.net/7mVHC/128/

I can fill below with:

```
 lines: {show: true, fill: true },
```

How can I get a different color for the portion above? I presume I could do a horizontal line equal to the maximum point, make it invisible and fill-between, but is there a better solution than that?

Answer (score 2):

Each point in a filled line accepts a third value, besides x and y, representing the value to fill to.  This defaults to zero, filling the area downwards.

If you instead use your maximum value, the area will be filled upwards.  In order to fill both up and down you'll need to duplicate your series, showing one as you do now and the other with no lines or points; only a fill upwards.

Comment: Can you give example code for this? I'm trying it now, but there is nothing in the specification for it. fill: boolean or number, fillColor: null or color/gradient

Comment: The third value is added to your points, not to the fill option.  For example [[0, 10, 100], [1, 20, 100], ...] will fill that line upwards towards 100 rather than down towards 0, the default.

Comment: Actually I fixed it with a hook using changing the default floor 0, once to a point greater than max, and once to 0, but I have to change the variable during the hook as it  doesn't seem I am able to run different hooks for different data series? Also is it alright if I edit your answer with an example, someone might find it useful.